# Custom Alert Notification IAlertNotifyHandler Handler not firing

Tags: 2010, alert, event-handlers

I'm trying to create a custom Alert Notification handler that implements `IAlertNotifyHandler` to intercept immediate alerts generated by changed to publishing pages.

I've followed [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20151023215032/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx), and also [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20100406075107/http://blogs.syrinx.com/blogs/sharepoint/archive/2008/04/28/custom-alert-handlers-part-1-of-2.aspx). I've also made changes to `alerttemplates.xml` in the 14 Hive, and run `stsadm -o updatealerttemplates`. I've also `iisreset` and made sure alerts are actually being generated by viewing the log file, which says it attempts to send alert emails.

But whatever I do, **I can't get my alert notification handler to fire**. I've tried both attaching to all the `w3wp.exe` processes with the Visual Studio 2010 debugger, and also tried writing to both the SharePoint log and the Windows Event log from within the handler. I get nothing.

This is the XML added for my custom alert notification handler:

```
<NotificationHandlerAssembly>
    MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=...
</NotificationHandlerAssembly>
<NotificationHandlerClassName>
    MyAssembly.MyClass
</NotificationHandlerClassName>
<NotificationHandlerProperties></NotificationHandlerProperties>
```

I've added this to the two built-in alert templates for `SPAlertTemplateType.GenericList` and `SPAlertTemplateType.WebPageLibrary`.

The class looks like this:

```
public class MyAlertNotifyHandler : IAlertNotifyHandler {
    public bool OnNotification(SPAlertHandlerParams ahp) {
        // ...
```

Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

The AlertTemplate actually being used when making changes to a Publishing Page in a *Pages* list in a Publishing Web is the `SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary`.

**Adding the handler to the properties of this alert template makes the handler run.**

Very strange though - I would have thought the *Pages* list in a Publishing Web would match `SPAlertTemplateType.WebPageLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach to the OWSTimer service for debugging; run the Immediate Alerts job to execute the alerts. I usually restart the timer service before I attach to the process.